# Processing an IplImage(OpenCV) data in Tesseract

Tags: opencv, tesseract

I need to process images which i get from OpenCV.

I wrote so far:

```
IplImage* img=0;

img=cvLoadImage("paket2.tif");


api.SetRectangle(0,0,img->width, img->height);
api.SetImage((uchar*)img->imageData,img->width,img->height,img->depth/8,img->width*(img->depth/8));
//i tried also below line
//api.SetImage((uchar*)img->imageData,img->width,img->height,img->depth/8,img->widthStep);

int left,top,right,bottom;
left=0;top=0;right=0;bottom=0;
api.Recognize(NULL);
tesseract::ResultIterator *ri=api.GetIterator();
char * sonuc=(*ri).GetUTF8Text(tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL);

if((*ri).BoundingBox(tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL,&left,&top,&right,&bottom))
{printf("bb dogru\n");printf("%d,%d,%d,%d",left,top,right,bottom);}
printf("sonuc:%s",sonuc);
```

if i pass IplImage->widthStep to bytes perline, i have "wrong" boundingBox in left and right values and can not read all the text in the image.

if i pass IplImage->width*(IplImage->depth/8), boundingBox function returns false.

I hope you have some idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `IplImage* img=0;

img=cvLoadImage("paket2copy.png");
printf("width:%d",img->width);
printf("byte depth:%d",img->depth/8);
printf("widthStep:%d",img->widthStep);` result: width:642 byte depth:1 widthStep:1928; is this normal, byte per pixel is 1 but widthstep is 3 times bigger than width?

Comment: could you please post your code, if you have found a working solution in the meantime?

Comment: unfortunately not an exact solution. But i think to get letters(as conjunct black shapes) with opencv and send letter by letter to tesseract to recognize them. but in my situation this is enough because i do not need left right bounds, i only need up and down bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Copy your submatrix to a new IplImage. Create a tesseract image header with the correct info(width, height, step). Link the tesseract data pointer to the iplImage data pointer.

I can't remember how to access tesseract pointer, but for opencv is image->data.ptr

Answer (score 1):

This code here worked for me:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess; 
tess.Init(argv[0], "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT); 
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("...");
tess.SetImage((uchar*)image .data, image.size().width, image.size().height, image.channels(),     image.step1());
tess.Recognize(0);
const char* out = tess.GetUTF8Text();
```

Comment: Your codes not about processing. And your results must very bad.